# ros nodes not shutting down

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a launch file which first launch another launch file and then it starts another node. When my another node terminates I expect nodes started by first launch file should also terminate. So I have

```
 while (ros::ok())
```

in my first launch node so if my second node finishes, i want to terminate first node. but right now on console I get

> "escalating to SIGTERM"

. How do I fix this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302729/ros-nodes-not-shutting-down/) by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-08**:
Nodes not shutting down is typically caused by either not checking `ros::ok()` or not having a proper `ros::Rate::sleep()` somewhere in your `while` loop. The first is probably not the case, but do please check the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not how it works.

If a node "finishes" its execution, the other nodes could still keep spinning.
A node is killed when its node handler goes out of scope or when `ros::shutdown()` is called.

You can find a detailed description of initialization and shutdown here http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1